# How to show income in intent string array at recyclerview android?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-recyclerview

In my application I have draft messages which I can edit. Some of my drafts include attachments which I try to send to my edit activity and show it at recyclerview. In general I have managed to send my string arraylist and get it at my activity. But I can't show my attached files, especially their names at the recyclerview. I tried to make smth like that:

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

but it didn't help me.

So, firstly I get from my message names of attached files:

```
file_name = Objects.requireNonNull(response.body()).getAttachesNames();
```

then put this names into arraylist:

```
nameList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(file_name));
```

such result I can see in my logs:

```
W: [eZV9f.jpg, index.html]
```

and then I send my list via intent to another activity:

```
intent2.putStringArrayListExtra("attached_files", (ArrayList<String>) nameList);
```

receiving data from intent:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
extras = intent.getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
if (extras.containsKey("attached_files")) {
draft_files = getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("attached_files");
Log.w("MY_TAG", String.valueOf(draft_files));
}
}
```

results from logcat:

```
W: [eZV9f.jpg, index.html]
```

initialising of my adapter and recyclerview:

```
adapter = new AttachedFileAdapter(mNames);
recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(WriteResponseMess.this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
```

and then I try to get single element from this list and add to my ArrayList<>:

```
for (int i = 0; i < draft_files.size(); i++) {
mNames.addAll(Collections.singleton(draft_files.get(i)));
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
Log.w("MY_TAG", draft_files.get(i));
Log.w("MY_TAG", String.valueOf(mNames));
}
```

all previous pieces of code are used at my onCreate() method and as a result of all these actions I would like to see income data from another activity. Sometimes I managed to do it, but one element contained all income data and looked like this:

```
[eZV9f.jpg, index.html]
```

and it was wrong for me. I try to create the list which will contain all elements separately. I also tried to use some info from this [link](https://www.dotnetperls.com/collections-addall-java) which is connected with Collections, but I didn't manage to reach the goal of my task. In general I'm sure that the solution is very simple but I can't see it.

### update

all my activity class has more than 1000 lines and I will share all code which is connected with adding attachments and show attached data at my writing form:

Here is my dialog for getting directory list and choosing some files:

```
@Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        Dialog dialog = null;
        switch (id) {
            case CUSTOM_DIALOG_ID:
                dialog = new Dialog(WriteResponseMess.this, android.R.style.Theme_DeviceDefault_Light_NoActionBar_Fullscreen);
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_layout);
                dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);

                Toolbar toolbar = dialog.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_d);
                toolbar.setTitle("Add a new file.");

                textFolder = dialog.findViewById(R.id.folder);
                buttonUp = dialog.findViewById(R.id.up);
                buttonUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        ListDir(curFolder.getParentFile());
                    }
                });


                dialog_ListView = dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialoglist);

                final Dialog finalDialog1 = dialog;
                dialog_ListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
                        File selected = new File(curFolder, fileList.get(position));
                        if (selected.isDirectory()) {
                            ListDir(selected);
                        }
                        if (selected.isFile()) {
                            if (array.size() == 0) {
                                array = uploadFiles(array, selected.getName(), convertFileToString(selected.getPath()));
                                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                getImages();
                            } else {
                                if (array.toString().contains(selected.getName())) {
                                    Toast.makeText(WriteResponseMess.this, R.string.attaching_message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                    getImages();
                                } else {
                                    array = uploadFiles(array, selected.getName(), convertFileToString(selected.getPath()));
                                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                    getImages();
                                }

                            }
                            finalDialog1.dismiss();
                            ms.setArray(array);
                        }
                    }
                });

                break;
        }

        return dialog;
    }
```

and method for showing attached list, and in general this method works when I create a new message and attach a new file, it works fine:

```
private void getImages() {
        mNames.clear();
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {
            JsonObject object = array.get(i).getAsJsonObject();
            if (extras != null) {
                if (extras.containsKey("attached_files")) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < draft_files.size(); j++) {
                        mNames.clear();
                        mNames.add(draft_files.get(j));
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                        //Log.w("MY_TAG", draft_files.get(i));
                        Log.w("MY_TAG", String.valueOf(mNames));
                    }
                    mNames.add(object.get("filename").toString().substring(1, object.get("filename").toString().length() - 1));
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    //Log.w("MY_TAG", Arrays.toString(draft_files));
                    Log.w("MY_TAG", Arrays.toString(new ArrayList[]{mNames}));
                } else {
                    mNames.add(object.get("filename").toString().substring(1, object.get("filename").toString().length() - 1));
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    Log.w("MY_TAG", String.valueOf(mNames));
                }
            }


        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

no need to set Adapter twice . remove this line

```
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

From

```
for (int i = 0; i < draft_files.size(); i++) {
    mNames.addAll(Collections.singleton(draft_files.get(i)));
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    //recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter); no need
    Log.w("MY_TAG", draft_files.get(i));
    Log.w("MY_TAG", String.valueOf(mNames));
}
```

Comment: but I still don't see any items at my recyclerview.

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko please share full code of activity until i can better help